# measure execution times of function

Tags: php, function, microtime

PHP

```
$totalTimeFunction=0;
function f1()
{
     $t1=microtime(true);
    for($i=0;$i<900;$i++)
    {}
    $t2=microtime(true);
    $p=($t2-$t1);
    $GLOBALS['totalTimeFunction']+=$p;  
}


 $t1=microtime(true);
f1();
$t2=microtime(true);
$p=($t2-$t1);
echo 'OutFunction='.$p."\n";
echo 'inFunction='.$GLOBALS['totalTimeFunction']."\n";
```

[Online Code](http://ideone.com/UaX8af)

why outFunction is greater than inFunction?

Why outFunction is not equal to inFunction?

In my real function i connect to  database and do many  calculations and ... the time difference between inFunction and outFunction is 10 second?(timeline for  ajax is about equals to outFunction time)

**Edit**
My real function (table content has 100,000 record and i call it 100 times,difference between inFunction and outFunction is 10 second)

```
 $contentTable=array();
function getNameTask($id)
{ 
     $t=microtime(true);


    if(empty($GLOBALS['contentTable']))
    {       
        $baseClass = new MsDatabase();   
        $query = "select CON_VALUE,CON_ID,CON_CATEGORY from content where CON_LANG='fa' and (CON_CATEGORY='TAS_TITLE' or CON_CATEGORY='PRO_TITLE' )";

        $GLOBALS['contentTable']= $baseClass->query($query,WF_WORKFLOW_DB_NAME_MARKAZE);            
    }

    foreach($GLOBALS['contentTable'] as $R)
    {

        if(trim($R['CON_ID'])==trim($id) && $R['CON_VALUE']!='' && trim($R['CON_CATEGORY'])=='TAS_TITLE' ){
            $t2=microtime(true);
             $p=($t2-$t);
            $GLOBALS['tt']+=$p;  
             return $R["CON_VALUE"];
        }
    }

     return 0;          

}
```

Comment: outFunction will be greater than inFunction because it also measures the additional overheads of calling the function, and of executing the timing test (the calls to microtime) inside the function

Comment: but in my real function difference is 10 second?this is very much for me

Comment: Can't explain that 10 second difference without seeing the real function and its caller

Comment: @MarkBaker i added real function

Comment: Fault with your real function is that your in function timing is ignoring instantiation of the MsDatabase class, the database query (which will be a big time overhead), the if tests and related trims, etc; the out function timing will include these.... they could easily add up to a significant time difference, especially the database query, and especially if the table doesn't have appropriate indexing

Comment: no, i set `$t=microtime(true);` in first line of function , and $t set before MsDatabase and query

Comment: I missed that..... but check your indexes to ensure that the database query is running efficiently; and caling any database query 100 times is always going to be a big overhead

Comment: You're not doing any time measurement if there are no matching records found.

Comment: yes,but all time this found record